# Save and hide notifications and then show them later

Tags: notifications, tasker, do-not-disturb

Is there any way I could hide notifications from certain apps entire, but then have them appear later at some specific time or event? Essentially, I'd like to contextually delay notifications intentionally.

I know there are plenty of apps that can log notifications, or even roll them up into a single notification. Theses are very close to what I want, except I don't want the notifications to be intercepted at all times, and I don't even want to see that notifications have been blocked until some predetermined time or I check on them myself.

I'm pretty sure I'd have to hack together a solution, maybe using Tasker to prevent some of these apps from working and hiding the notifications from these notification loggers.

I'm on a stock, unrooted Galaxy S8 (Android 7.0).

Comment: Please add device and OS version, whether rooted or not on your question by editing it

Comment: Never tried, but I'm pretty sure the right combination of [notification tools](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_notifications) should be able to achieve this. E.g. [Notification Inbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wandoujia.notification) can clear unwanted notifications, and you can watch them later with [Past Notifications](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.coconuts.pastnotifications).